# How can I pass strings with single quotes to grep?

Tags: grep, find, xargs, escape-characters

My desired outcome is the following: to recursively search a directory looking for a given string in all found files. The following command is my usual port of call:

```
find ./ | xargs grep -ns 'foobar'
```

However, when `foobar` has quotes the command fails and gives me a `>` prompt in the shell. The specific command that's causing the problem is as follows:

```
find ./ | xargs grep -ns 'add_action(\'save_post\','
```

I've tried to escape the quotes with backslashes but to no avail. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Single quotes are terminated by single quotes; all other characters in between are preserved exactly as is, including backslashes.  Thus there is no way to embed a single quote between single quotes.  (But you *can* end the single quotes, escape a single quote, and start a new set of single quotes, as in `'Single quotes aren'\''t ever really embedded in single quotes.'`)

**Suggestion:** Avoid find+xargs when `grep -r pattern .` can recursively grep on the current directory.

The below commands have equivalent behavior:

```
grep -rns "add_action('save_post'," .
grep -rns 'add_action('\'save_post\', .
```

The last command is interpreted as:

1. `'add_action('` -> `add_action(`
2. `\'` -> `'`
3. `save_post` -> `save_post`
4. `\'` -> `'`
5. `,` -> `,`

Concatenating these parts, the `grep` command receives the argument `add_action('save_post',`.

Comment: great insight on the interpretation, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` expects arguments quoted in some strange way that `find` doesn't produce. Never use `xargs` in combination with `find`, unless you know that your file names don't contain `\"'` or whitespace.

Instead of using `xargs`, let `find` directly call the program you want to run.

```
find . -exec grep -ns 'add_action('\''save_post'\'',' {} +
```

With `exec … {} +`, the program is invoked once for many files at once, like with `xargs`. Some older versions of `find` don't support `+` here¹, then you have to use `;` instead, which invokes `grep` once per file.

You can alternatively use `find … -print0 | xargs -0`, if your utilities support it¹. The `-print0` option tells `find` to emit names separated by a null byte, and `-0` tells `xargs` to expect null-separated input and not to do any quote interpretation.

Note the quoting above: between single quotes, all characters are interpreted literally, except that `'` signifies the end of the literal string. So `'\''` is effectively a way of putting a literal single quote inside a single-quoted string; formally, it's “`'` end quote, `\` literal `'` single quote, `'` begin quote”.

In the special case of `grep`, if your implementation supports it¹, you can dispense with `find` and use `grep -r` to search inside a directory recursively:

```
grep -r 'add_action('\''save_post'\'',' .
```

¹  <sub>Linux, Cygwin, FreeBSD and OSX support these features.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the info about `-print0` and `-0`, I've looked at these options before but never understood them well enough to actually yield the results I needed. I'll be using `grep -rns` from now on.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "add_action('save_post'," ./* -R
```

1. You can grep all files in current directory recursively with `-R` option.
2. Search string can be surrounded with `"`.